# Reverse loop but skip first condition?

Tags: vba, excel

I am finding each page break and when i find one i am reverse looping on a column but i want to skip the first condition i find. Here's what i mean:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pb As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
    For i = pb.Location.Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then '<<--- HOW TO SKIP THE FIRST "1" I FIND BUT KEEP THE LOOP GOING BACKWARD?
            Dim counter As Long
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter = 1 Then '<<-- certainly not working...
                Exit For
            Else
                'Do Something
            End If
        End If
     Next
Next
```

[image]

EDIT: all i needed to do was remove  the exit for code and it work!

Comment: Code looks correct - what is it that's not working?

Comment: when i first find a "1" i want to skip that and find the second "1" instead.

Comment: Simply deleting the `Exit For` should be enough - but you also need to move the `Dim counter` line up, otherwise it is always equal to 1. It should be between the two `For` statements or before the first one, not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: ok, all i needed to do was removed the exit for and it worked lol

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue the loop get rid of `Exit For` and change your if statement to

```
If counter <> 1 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Then you stay in the full loop.

Comment: I just want to skip the first loop that finds "1" but i want to find the next "1" and do something.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter for the 1s found and increment it when you find one. If counter>1 then read it, otherwise ignore it.

On my phone so will add a specific code example later on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , you just need to change the location of the counter initialization and just check if counter is greater than 1.  I am assuming for each page break we skip the first.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pb As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
    Dim counter As Long = 0 ' Move this count outside the internal loop
    For i = pb.Location.Row To 1 Step -1
        If foundFirst AndAlso Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then '<<--- HOW TO SKIP THE FIRST "1" I FIND BUT KEEP THE LOOP GOING BACKWARD?
            counter = counter + 1
            'Only do it once your counter is above 1
            If counter <> 1 Then            
                'Do Something
            End If

        End If
     Next
Next
```